# jquery array not getting all the values as well as not sent to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I made two custom jquery function that gets an array of data when checkbox is checked. I tried to assign the array as the value of a input field (type=hidden) and sent it to laravel controller. The problem is the the array is not populated properly when i checked several fields. Its only take one value and sent it to the controller. I need to take all the checked values as array and sent it to laravel controller. Please help me in this regard. I pasted my stuffs below :

jquery:

```
<script>
    var allvals = [] ;

    function categoryDelete(){
        $('.categorySelect:checked').each(function(){
            allvals = $(this).val();
        })

        return allvals;
    }

    function subcategoryDelete(){
        $('.subcategorySelect:checked').each(function(){
            allvals = $(this).val();
        })

        return allvals;
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var deleteArray = [] ;

        $('.categorySelect').click(function(){
            deleteArray = categoryDelete();
            $('#deleteArray').attr('value',deleteArray);
            $('#deleteValue').attr('value',0);

        })

        $('.subcategorySelect').click(function(){
            deleteArray = subcategoryDelete();
            $('#deleteArray').attr('value',deleteArray);
            $('#deleteValue').attr('value',1);
        })
    })
</script>
```

html form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'manage-category/delete')) }}
<input type="hidden" id='deleteArray' name='deleteArray[]'>
<input type="hidden" id='deleteValue' name='deleteValue[]'>
<button id='deleteBtn' class="btn btn-sm red pull-right">
    Delete <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

routes:

```
Route::post('/manage-category/delete','CategoryController@deleteCategory');
```

controller:

```
public function deleteCategory()
{
    $deleteArray = Input::get('deleteArray');
    $deleteValue = Input::get('deleteValue');

    var_dump($deleteArray);
    die();
}
```

debug result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you say `allvals = $(this).val();` that is going to overwrite the value of allvals each time. So it'll only ever store the value of the last checked checkbox.

The solution is to append new values.

```
allvals.push($(this).val());
```

Comment: oh silly me .. yes u r right i forget the push staff.. bt a now it shows like 

array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "3,3,4" } 

why?

Comment: Yeah this is because inputs only store strings (they can't store complex objects like arrays). So when you set their value, it's converting the data to a string and giving you comma separated values. An easy solution (though maybe not the most robust) is to do $deleteArray = explode(',',$deleteArray[0]) to convert it back into an array on the server side. Read more here http://php.net/EXPLODE

Comment: thanks .. I know how explode works.. i just ask if any good solution has or not. Me too personally don't like the stuff.. bdw thanks a lot. can u please upvote the question?